# 2 different ajax functions called one after another return the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a bizarre behavior of 2 different ajax functions called one after another.
Each of them fetch different value and populate different text boxes but the problem is they return the value of the first function called.

here is the code:

```
if (id == "Other") {
    document.getElementById("Value").style.display = "block";
    document.myForm.Price.value = "";
    document.myForm.Code.value = "";
} else {
    document.getElementById("Value").style.display = "none";
    document.myForm.TypeValue.value = id;
    getCOde(id);
    getPrice(id);
}
```

here is `getPrice` function:

```
function getPrice(value) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { //safari, chrome, opera, ffox
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { //IE
        ActiveXObject("Microft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.AddingForm.itemPrice.value = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../scripts/getPrice.php?ID=" + value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

here is the `getCode` fucntion

```
function getCode(value) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { //safari, chrome, opera, ffox
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { //IE
        ActiveXObject("Microft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.AddingForm.itemCode.value = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../scripts/getyCode.php?ID=" + value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

both functions work well if only one of them is called. and beside if I interchange their order, than the value which is returned is the one of the first function called.

I wonder how to make one function to wait till another is executed. because i guess the order is the problem

Comment: the xmlhttp variable is global try `var xmlhttp` as the first line in each function (or use a different name in one function)

Comment: The question is not clear. Try adding more details..

Comment: why would you tag your question with `jQuery` when your using vanilla Javascript to perform Ajax functionality ? `JQuery.ajax()` is more easy and simple way to perform ajax, thats my suggestion. http://api.jquery.com/?s=jquery.ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare xmlhttp inside each function instead of having it as a global variable.

```
function getPrice(value){
var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){//safari, chrome, opera, ffox
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{//IE
     xmlhttp = ActiveXObject("Microft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

you are overriding the reference to one object with another so the object in the event handler refered to by the identifier xmlhttp is the same in both cases

Comment: in which function shall I do it? in both?

Comment: @mistersweet yes, by not declaring it you implicitly give it global scope, so you should always declare your variables in the function where you use them

Comment: the problem was with the lexical scope   lol :v , you are the man .. Keep it up@RuneFS